# Blazeface predictions returning negative x coordinates

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have my own Typescript Blazeface version up and running. The predictions rectangle however does not show up on the video overlay canvas. Debugging shows that the x coordinates returned from the predictions are negative. Is this user error or some other subtle bug in my code?

The source code can be found in this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/g_debailly/pen/zYGQKOe

This is the predictions array:

```
[
  {
    "topLeft": [
      -261.7025451660156,
      218.29611206054688
    ],
    "bottomRight": [
      -429.23638916015625,
      343.9468994140625
    ],
    "landmarks": [
      [
        -309.3980703353882,
        265.82969784736633
      ],
      [
        -374.39136600494385,
        260.38822889328003
      ],
      [
        -341.75953893363476,
        302.7327650785446
      ],
      [
        -344.2469654083252,
        320.3148329257965
      ],
      [
        -280.4582414627075,
        261.1372035741806
      ],
      [
        -415.7755718231201,
        250.6269371509552
      ]
    ],
    "probability": [
      0.9908785223960876
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the argument `const flipHorizontal = false` in the call to `model.estimateFaces()`.

Comment: after switching `flipHorizontal` the prediction rectangle responded by going the opposite horizontal direction. This I fixed by commenting out `transform: scaleX(-1);` in the style sheet. In the original demo there is a "twin" `<video>` element with `visibility: hidden`. Is that a workaround for the `flipHorizontal` behavior?